# Key error in request.params

Tags: python, shell, pyramid

I am a beginner in Python and I have to create a pyramid project that accepts user input from a from, and performs a simple operation that gives back the result to the user. 
This is my views.py

```
 from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config
@view_config(route_name="home",renderer='templates/ui.pt')
def my_view(request):
    myvar=request.params['command']
    return Response(myvar)
```

This is my templates/ui.pt (excluding all initial html,head tags)

```
    <form action="my_view" method="POST"><input type="text" name="command"/>
<input type="submit" name="go" value="submit"/></form>
</html>
```

When I run this, I get this error
**Keyerror:'command'**

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no parameters are passed in your request (which is what would happen if you visit the page without posting to it or adding a param to the query string -- http://mypage/my_view?command=something), then the request.params MultiDict won't have a key named 'command' in it and that's where your error is coming from.  You can either explicitly check if 'command' is in your request.params:

```
myvar = None
if 'command' in request.params:
    myvar = request.params['command']
```

Or you can (more commonly) use the get method of a dictionary to supply a default value:

```
myvar = request.params.get('command', None)
```

Also since you're defining a template for your view, typically, your return value would be something that provides context to that template.  Your code, however, isn't actually using the template but is instead directly returning a Response.  You normally wouldn't do that.   You'd do something more like this:

```
@view_config(route_name="home",renderer='templates/ui.pt')
def my_view(request):
    myvar=request.params.get('command',None)
    return {'myvar': myvar }
```

And then in your template you'd reference the object it got passed:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST"><input type="text" name="command"/>
<input type="submit" name="go" value="submit"/></form>
<div tal:condition="myvar">
   You entered <tal:block tal:content="myvar"></tal:block>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a walkthrough from scratch to get the above working:

Install pyramid:

```
pip install pyramid
```

Create your pyramid project:

```
pcreate -t starter myproject
```

Set up the environment for your project:

```
cd myproject
python setup.py develop
```

Replace the myproject/views.py with:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config

@view_config(route_name="home",renderer='templates/ui.pt')
def my_view(request):
    myvar=request.params.get('command',None)
    return {'myvar': myvar }
```

Add the myproject/templates/ui.pt file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST"><input type="text" name="command"/>
<input type="submit" name="go" value="submit"/></form>
<div tal:condition="myvar">
   You entered <tal:block tal:content="myvar"></tal:block>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Start up your app:

```
pserve --reload development.ini
```

Visit your pyramid site:

```
http://localhost:6543
```

Comment: I get the first part of your explanation. It worked fine when I tried appending the param to my query string. But when I type something into my textbox and hit submit it says 404 not found /my_view. Moreover, it doesnt work when I tried without appending the param to my query. Can you please tell me how to submit something through the textbox, and get it printed down without appending my params in the query string?

Comment: I didn't notice your form action.  The action tells the browser what url to post the form data to.  You want it to post to itself, so get rid of the action altogether. <form method="POST">

Comment: I tried removing the action attribute but still I dont get what I type inside the textbox when I hit submit. It just clears itself. Also, I dont get this page unless I give in the command param explicitly in the query string.

Comment: Btw I added config.add_route('home', '/') in my __init.py__ file. Yet the localhost:6543/ page doesnt get  my to this form. Did i miss something?

Comment: Your __init__.py should have already had your home view in it.  I added a walkthrough from scratch.  I was assuming that you'd already read through the quick tutorial to get as far as you had gotten with it.  If you haven't you should take a look at Steve's link and follow it through.  The pyramid documentation is really pretty good.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help it runs perfectly well. I tried adding two more lines to my code whoch messed up things. In my views.py.... If you can help me I will post them here.

Answer (score 0):

The best place for beginners to start learning Pyramid is from its documentation, specifically the [Quick Tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/index.html).

The Quick Tutorial steps through a progression of topics leading toward web forms.

Comment: Hi steve! Thanks I went through this tutorial it was very useful.